# Apple APP rejection - Reason Metadata

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

just need an information as I submitted the app and apple gave me this reason.

> Guideline 2.3.10 - Performance We noticed that your app or its metadata includes irrelevant third-party platform information."

Does it only relate to metadata information provided or it can also be due to the third party library used in the code?

I have used the following pod files, does anyone know if any of it contradicts apple policies for APP approval?

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
pod 'MZTimerLabel'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

Comment: don't see any issue with pod file here. Definitely issue with your store description. Paste your store description in question.

Answer (score 19):

Check screenshot and description...

***if screenshots have Android background apple will reject...***

***if your description have Android word, apple will reject***

***Anything in your app should not contain Android logo/ Samsung device/ Android word.***

***If they see test word in your app, they will reject it.***

*Welcome to world of Apple*

Comment: Yes, Its Apple. Most of the time application rejected for the reason you mention

Comment: I have included android url in description ..  my app got rejected .. i didn't know till i see this answer .. its really helpful

Comment: @FahimParkar: It has been 3 years and your answer still be able to save my life. In my case, I have the word "Google Play" and bam. You are legend

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the metadata. You can follow up by responding to the review - ask for more specific information on why you got rejected. I would start going through the App Icon, Description, Screenshots, Whats New, and Tags.

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using firebase then go to ios folder > GoogleService-info.plist file and remove the below key from your info.plist file.**

```
<key>ANDROID_CLIENT_ID</key>
<string>95532567432253- 
      53s9madfilp0kit72nv0mpiqg3rrcadt.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
```